# contentsOfFile: - "Use of unresolved identifier 'contentsOfFile'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to read data from simple `CSV` Text File called `data.txt` that is saved in my main folder. I get an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'contentsOfFile' where shown in code

Where am I going wrong?

```
//MARK: Data reading and writing functions

func readDataFromFile(fileName:String) -> String!{
    guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt")

    else {return nil}
    do { //Error showing following line
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)  

        return contents
    }catch{
        print ("File Read Error")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiles fine here. Are you using Swift3?

Comment: The Swift 3 code is correct, however you should not return an implicit unwrapped optional.